# He Hayedyia before the letter Chet. Segol or Patach?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

in Achare Mot the verses say:

> וְהִקְרִ֖יב אֶת־הַשָּׂעִ֥יר הֶחָֽי׃ כא וְסָמַ֨ךְ אַהֲרֹ֜ן אֶת־שְׁתֵּ֣י יָדָ֗ו עַ֣ל רֹ֣אשׁ הַשָּׂעִיר֮ הַחַי֒

The first occurence on the end of a verse is Hechay, and the Second with a weaker interruptive pisuk is Hachay.

What is the reason of the difference.

The Minchat Shay addresses this and if I understand, he doesn't explain it grammatically but gives a mnemonic to remember.

> את השעיר החי – קדמאה בסגול תניי בפתח וחד פסוק סימן (ר״ל כמו מן הם המדברים בתיבה השנייה ה״א בפתח כן החי תניין בפתח וכמו האנכי הריתי בתיבה הראשונה הה״א בסגול כן החי קדמאה בסגול, ובדעת האחד נודע השני ולא כדוחק המהרש״ד בת״ס שלו, ולי בחרתי הסימן החכם עניו בראשו, והכסיל בחושך הולך.) הם המדברים סימן אחר האנוכי הריתי.‏

Is there despite that a logical explanation?